# Invisible Gridview column gets 0 value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` which I use to pass info to another page row by row. But when I make a column invisible, it passes on 0 as the value. Here is my `GridView`, having problems with `TaskId`.

```aspx
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
              Width="936px" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
              OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" style="text-align: center" 
              BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" 
              BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2" 
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
              AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskId" HeaderText="TaskId" Visible="false" 
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TaskId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" HeaderText="Body" 
                        SortExpression="Body" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reward" HeaderText="Reward(Rs)" 
                        SortExpression="Reward" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeAllotted" HeaderText="Time(Min)" 
                        SortExpression="TimeAllotted" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PosterName" HeaderText="Uploader" 
                        SortExpression="PosterName" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" 
                         Text="Perform Task" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White"  
                         ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true">
            <ControlStyle BackColor="#CC6600" Font-Bold="True" 
                          ForeColor="White"/>
        </asp:ButtonField>
    </Columns>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [**`DataKeyNames`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `GridView`.

Specify your invisible Column names in it if you want to access their values:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="TaskId" .../>
```

You can access the Value as:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{    
    int TASKID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);
}
```